# Can't connect DocumentDB to EC2 on same VPC in same region

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-documentdb

My docdb and ec2 instances are on the same VPC in the same region.
My docdb security group allows all inbound traffic, my EC2 security group allows any RDP

I've followed all the troubleshooting steps on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html

and I'm still not able to connect.
I'm using a Windows EC2

the error i get:

```
mongo --ssl --host URL:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username username --password password
MongoDB shell version v3.6.13
connecting to: mongodb://URL:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-06-27T15:31:02.086+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to IP:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2019-06-27T15:31:02.088+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server URL:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

[image]

Comment: You mentioned they are on the same VPC. Are they on the same subnets? If not, can the subnets route/talk to each other? Does the URL translate to a private IP?

Comment: @jefftrotman looks like docdb is on us-west-2c whereas ec2 is on us-west-2b. how do i match them up? (the URL does translate to a private IP)

Comment: @jefftrotman , I managed to get them on the same subnet but the same issue persists

Comment: @BelgoCanadian, this is not expected. Are you still having an issue?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek I cloned the EC2 instance and made sure the new one was on us-west-2c. problem solved for now...

Comment: Where we have to run all that AWS command. I am working on ubuntu machine. Pls heelp me I am new user??